# ASP MVC Ajax status 200 but parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm freaking out...I have a project that was working ok (in fact, in the hosting is working), but locally all Ajax requests return Status 200 but a parsererror error. The weird part, is that in the responseText I get the right response BUT with a comment at the end:

*<--142,6021ms-->* what is that??

[image: Response]

This is my request:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Usuarios/Authenticate',
                type: "POST",
                data: { username: $('input[name=username]').val(), password: $('input[name=password]').val() },
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.Success) location.href = '/';
                    else {
                        ShowError(msg.Message);
                    }

                    CloseLoading();
                },
                error: function (data, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(data);
                    ShowError(ERR_UNKNOWN);
                    CloseLoading();
                }
            });
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Pro, Windows 10 x64. I didn't touch anything after the last access. I just opened the project, right-click and view in Chrome.

Thanksss!!

Comment: It looks like an html comment was attached to your server response, which makes it invalid JSON, therefore the parse error.

Comment: @Jasen exactly! but I can't find out why...I've been spending the last 3 hours in this...

Comment: Start by examining the server-side code and running the debugger there to step through the request.

Comment: @Jasen the thing is that the same code was working fine (without any changes), I don't know what it could be...maybe a Visual Studio issue? iis?

Comment: @Jasen also, the "comment" is added to every ajax response...I don't have a clue where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered that I added this to my web.config file

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <add name="TimingModule" type="[...]" />
</modules>
```

That adds the comment to the response...

Comment: Please watch your language. Also, is this a solution to the issue or additional information to your question?

Comment: @gunr2171 what I've said? This is the solution. That's why is posted "Thanks anyway!"...

Comment: It was "dumba**" that was the problematic phrase. And just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @gunr2171 but I was referencing to how I'm feeling for spending so much time on a simple solution...anyway, thanks!